# powershell / runspace in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell

I'm running the following code :

```
RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException warning;
config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out warning);
if (warning != null) throw warning;            

Runspace thisRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
thisRunspace.Open();

string alias = usr.AD.CN.Replace(' ', '.');
string letter = usr.AD.CN.Substring(0, 1);
string email = alias + "@" + (!usr.Mdph ? Constantes.AD_DOMAIN : Constantes.MDPH_DOMAIN) + "." + Constantes.AD_LANG;
string db = "CN=IS-" + letter + ",CN=SG-" + letter + ",CN=InformationStore,CN=" + ((char)letter.ToCharArray()[0] < 'K' ? Constantes.EXC_SRVC : Constantes.EXC_SRVD) + Constantes.EXC_DBMEL;
string cmd = "Enable-Mailbox -Identity \"" + usr.AD.CN + "\" -Alias " + alias + " -PrimarySmtpAddress " + email + " -DisplayName \"" + usr.AD.CN + "\" -Database \"" + db + "\"";
Pipeline thisPipeline = thisRunspace.CreatePipeline(cmd);
thisPipeline.Invoke();
```

The code is running in a thread created that way :

```
        t.WorkThread = new Thread(cu.CreerUser);
        t.WorkThread.Start();
```

If I run the code directly (not through a thread), it's working.

When in a thread it throws the following exception : ObjectDisposedException "The safe handle has been closed." (Translated from french)

I then replaced "Open" wirh "OpenAsync" which helped not getting the previous exception.
But when on Invoke I get the following exception : InvalidRunspaceStateException "Unable to call the pipeline because its state of execution is not Opened. Its current state is Opening." (Also translated from french)

I'm clueless...

Any help welcome !!!
Thanks !!!

---

With Open:

```
   à Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
   à System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass, UInt32& dwLength)
   à System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
   à System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
   à System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
   à System.Management.Automation.MshLog.GetLogContext(ExecutionContext executionContext, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Severity severity)
   à System.Management.Automation.MshLog.GetLogContext(ExecutionContext executionContext, InvocationInfo invocationInfo)
   à System.Management.Automation.MshLog.LogEngineLifecycleEvent(ExecutionContext executionContext, EngineState engineState, InvocationInfo invocationInfo)
   à System.Management.Automation.MshLog.LogEngineLifecycleEvent(ExecutionContext executionContext, EngineState engineState)
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace.OpenHelper()
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.CoreOpen(Boolean syncCall)
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.Open()
   à Cg62.ComposantsCommuns.ActiveDirectory.Exchange.BoitesAuxLettres.CreationBAL(User usr, IList`1 log) dans D:\Applications\Commun\Sources  .Net\COMIAD\COMIAD\Exchange.cs:ligne 141
   à Cg62.ComposantsCommuns.ActiveDirectory.ComptesUtilisateurs.CreationUser.CreerUser() dans D:\Applications\Commun\Sources  .Net\COMIAD\COMIAD\ComptesUtilisateurs.cs:ligne 199
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

With OpenAsync:

```
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.AddToRunningPipelineList(PipelineBase pipeline)
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.DoConcurrentCheckAndAddToRunningPipelines(PipelineBase pipeline, Boolean syncCall)
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.CoreInvoke(IEnumerable input, Boolean syncCall)
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   à System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
   à Cg62.ComposantsCommuns.ActiveDirectory.Exchange.BoitesAuxLettres.CreationBAL(User usr, IList`1 log) dans D:\Applications\Commun\Sources  .Net\COMIAD\COMIAD\Exchange.cs:ligne 149
   à Cg62.ComposantsCommuns.ActiveDirectory.ComptesUtilisateurs.CreationUser.CreerUser() dans D:\Applications\Commun\Sources  .Net\COMIAD\COMIAD\ComptesUtilisateurs.cs:ligne 199
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Sorry for the late reply... I had a lot going on

---

Upgraded to Powershell 2.0 and I got past the Open error
but now I have the following on the Invoke. 
I changed my command to :

```
Enable-Mailbox -Identity "Aagtest Abe" -Alias Aagtest.Abe -PrimarySmtpAddress smtp.address@domain.com -DisplayName "Aagtest Abe" -Database "myDb" -DomainController adc.domain.int
```

The command works fine from powershell.
I get the following exception CmdletInvocationException :
"Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour '<Module>'."
No idea on how to translate that...

StackTrace :

```
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.DSAccessTopologyProvider..ctor(String machineName)
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.DSAccessTopologyProvider..ctor()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.DirectoryServicesTopologyProvider.DiscoverConfigDC()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.DirectoryServicesTopologyProvider..ctor()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.InitializeInstance()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.GetInstance()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConnection(String preferredServer, Boolean isWriteOperation, Boolean isNotifyOperation, ADObjectId& rootId)
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetReadConnection(String preferredServer, ADObjectId& rootId)
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.IsReadConnectionAvailable()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientObjectActionTask`2.InternalBeginProcessing()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox.InternalBeginProcessing()
   à Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.BeginProcessing()
   à System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()
   à System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you ever received an answer? The problem appears in code that has worked fine for two years (tested on Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003). But ever since we deployed on Windows Server 2008 we get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the final answer to that problem is you can't execute remote Exchange powershell commands if you impersonate through advapi32 LogonUser.

Wether the commands are executed in a thread or not don't matter at all as far as I tested.

What seem to be the correct way - well the one that works for me - is to authenticate right after you connect to the Runspace.

As to why this happens... feel free to tell me !!

This code **must not** be executed while impersonating.

```
        IContexteRemotePowerShell crp:
        crp.ConfigurationName = "Microsoft.Exchange";
        crp.RemoteUri = "http://exhangeserver/powershell";
        crp.User = "account who has rights to do stuff on the exchange server";
        crp.Password = "its password";
        crp.Domaine = "Domain";


private static void Connect(IContexteRemotePowerShell contexte)
    {
        try
        {
            Espace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            Espace.Open();
        }
        catch (InvalidRunspaceStateException ex)
        {
            throw new TechniqueException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), "Error while creating runspace.", ex);
        }

        // Create secure password
        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in contexte.Password)
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }

        // Create credential
        PSCredential psc = new PSCredential(contexte.User, password);

        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
        command.AddParameter("Credential", psc);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contexte.Serveur))
            command.AddParameter("computername", contexte.Serveur);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contexte.RemoteUri))
            command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(contexte.RemoteUri));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contexte.ConfigurationName))
            command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", contexte.ConfigurationName);

        //// Create the session
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Runspace = Espace;
        Collection<PSObject> result = ExecuterCommande(command);

        if (result.Count != 1)
            throw new TechniqueException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(),
                                            "Error while connecting.");

        // Create session variable
        command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
        command.AddParameter("Name", "ra");
        command.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
        ExecuterCommande(command);
    }

private const string InvokeCommand = "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {{ {0} }} -Session $ra";

    private static string ExecuteRemoteScript(string cmd)
    {
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddScript(string.Format(InvokeCommand, cmd));
        Collection<PSObject> result = ExecuterCommande(command);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in result)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
//set the default runspace for this thread
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace = runspace;
```

Answer (score 1):

What goes wrong when you call `Runspace.Open` from another thread is a symptom of the same problem described [here](http://winterdom.com/2008/12/crashingyourprocesswithtimers). I had the exact same problem in a web project where I started a new thread from the thread that served the request. The new thread eventually called the `Enable-Mailbox` cmdlet.

The problem in my case was that the web request itself had long finished before the call to `Runspace.Open` occurred. The web request is associated with a [`WindowsIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) that is stored on the thread. The identity is passed to the thread that calls `Runspace.Open`. However, since the thread that handles the web request finishes before this call, the identity is disposed before the runspace is opened. Somewhere during the `Runspace.Open` call, an attempt is made to get the security token of the now disposed identity (see the first line in your stacktrace: `Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation`). This fails with an `ObjectDisposedException`.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Do not call `Runspace.Open` from another thread. At least not when the calling thread finishes before `Runspace.Open` is called.
2. Make sure there is another identity on the thread before you call `Runspace.Open`. For example, you can do the following:

   ```
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
       new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("PSTest"), null)
   ```

   What you fill in for the name of the `GenericIdentity` doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Ronald. Even if your answer did not help the OP, it helped me.

I was running into an issue just trying to launch something in an AppDomain on a web server. Right on the line:

```
ObjectHandle handle = domain.CreateInstance(_assemblyName, _className);
```

...it exploded with an ObjectDisposedException. I could not figure it out for the life of me - nothing in the AppDomain was being disposed, and this seemed to be working on other servers.

I stepped into the disassembly, and saw it trying to serialize the thread execution context, the logical call context contained in that, and the principal contained in that, and the principal is what it exploded on.

It turned out that the thread on which this was running was created when a user was logged on, and IIS was in 'impersonate' mode, so the thread's current principal was the expired principal of that original user.

I put this around the code:

```
IPrincipal oldPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
try
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(
        new GenericIdentity("NetPlugins"), null);
    ObjectHandle handle = domain.CreateInstance(_assemblyName, _className);
    // unwrapping and calling code omitted
}
finally
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = oldPrincipal;
}
```

I probably need not put the old principal back, and could also probably solve this by changing the current principal before creating the thread in question, but thank you, Ronald: this works like a top!